# change only the first two numbers of a input field in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need a text input field, that allows the user to enter only the first two numbers of a thousand value. The three zeros after the seperator should be fixed.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I use React and for the other input field I use the [React-Input-Mask](https://github.com/sanniassin/react-input-mask)

Comment: Use input mask https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom mask. Suppose it is as follows. If I understood you.

```
var MyMaskIntput = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            val: ""
        };
    },
    handleChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({ val: e.target.value });
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        var $elem = $(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.maskedInput));
        var reverse = { reverse: false };

        if (this.props.isReverse) {
            reverse = { reverse: true };
        }

        $elem.mask(this.props.mask, reverse);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (<div>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} ref="maskedInput"></input>
            {this.state.val}
        </div>);
    }
});

React.render(
    <div>
        KM = <MyMaskIntput isReverse={true} mask={"#0.000"} /><br />
    </div>
    , document.getElementById("content"));
```

It will return the following result. If you enter 1s.
11.111 
And you can also put some limit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Only the first two numbers shoud be changeable, the rest should be fixed. E.g. 12.000, 15.000 22.000 ...